Oxidation of 1,2 dicarbonyls by tollens reagent
According to the wiki page on Tollen's reagent
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent#Qualitative_organic_analysis

It also gives a positive test with hydrazines, hydrazones, α-hydroxy ketones and 1,2-dicarbonyls.

It is clear that $\alpha$-hydroxy ketones that tautomerize into aldehydes are (mostly) able to give this test, and are oxidized to 1,2-dicarbonyls.
Hence, how exactly would 1,2-dicarbonyls be further oxidized by tollens reagent?
